# Image cannot be found AJAX(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have AJAX call

Here is code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    email_update();
});

function email_update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EmailsList", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var email = result;
            // console.log(result[0].Name);
            for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++) {
                var emailHTML = '<div style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 10px;>' +
                    '<b style="margin-left: 10px;">' +(i + 1) +
                    '<b style="margin-left:20px;">' + result[i].Email + '</b>'+
                    '<b>' +
                    '<b style="margin-left: 20px;">' +
                    result[i].Name +
                    '</b>' + '<a style="float: right; margin-right: 20px;">' +
                    '<img src="~/Images/Edit.png">' +
                    '</a>' +
                    '<a style="float: right; margin-right: 20px;">' +
                    '<img src="~/Images/Delete.png">' +
                    '</a>' +
                    '</div>';
                $(".email_list").append(emailHTML);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But I facing trouble

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

But image is in folder

I was having this code before (not in AJAX) `<a style="float: right; margin-right: 20px;" href='@Url.Action("Edit_mail", "Questions", new {id = item.Individ_Id})'>
                            <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")'/>
                        </a>`

where can be my mistake?

Comment: Was that working before ajax because paths seems to be an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its due to the reason that `~` has no significance in JavaScript/HTML. In Razor [`@Url.Content()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx) converts virtual path to absolute path.

Use it as per you sample code or Store a reference in a variable and later use it

```
var editImage = '@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")'
```

usage

```
'<img src="' + editImage + '">'
```

Comment: Thank's  for help dude!